# How to write the right expression in RMarkdown inline code

Tags: r, r-markdown, inline

I want to use the results of a k-s test with an inline code using RMarkdown. I can get `ks$statistic[[1]]` and `ks$p.value[[1]]` but when I use them inline, I get an error.

````
---
title: "ks test2"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results="asis")
````

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(50)
ks <- ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean=mean(x),
        sd=sd(x))
df <- length(x)
```

Based on K-S test (`r D (df) = ks$statistic[[1]], p = ks$p.value[[1]]`), we can conlude something.
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have inline is not valid R code. Try something like this:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
x <- rnorm(50)
ks <- ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))
df <- length(x)
```

Based on K-S test (D(`r df`) = `r ks$statistic[[1]]`, p = `r ks$p.value[[1]]`), we can conlude something.
````

But you will likely want to format those numbers for printing so you might try something more like this:

```
Based on K-S test (D(`r df`) = `r format(round(ks$statistic[[1]], 2), nsmall = 2)`, p = `r format(round(ks$p.value[[1]], 2), nsmall = 2)`), we can conlude something.
```